# To Display row wise data using datatable in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, myfaces

```
<h:dataTable var="data" value="mBean.dataList">
 <h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
   <h:outputText value="Name">
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{data.name}"/>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Description">
    </f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{data.description}"/>
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The above code would fetch the result like this :

Name Decription
N1         D1
N2         D2
N3         D3
N4         D4

But I want the data to be displayed as :
N1
D1

N2
D2

N3
D3

N4
D4

Plz let me know how to achieve the above requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the structure you posted is correct, but:

every Tag have to be closed. in your code you have many `<h:outputText value="...">` without closing tag. correct it and it should work

Comment: Forget the code which i have written....... I want the code to display the data in row wise format i.e N1 D1 , N2 D2 , N3 D3

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but finally we got one solution on this quetion
below I am writting some code so you can use it as example.

```
 <h:dataTable var="data" value="mBean.dataList">
 <h:column> 
 <h:panalGrid column="2"> 
<f:facet name="header"> 
 <h:outputText value="Name">  
</f:facet>  
<h:outputText value="#{data.name}"/>  
</h:panalGrid>  <h:panalGrid column="2">    
<f:facet name="header">     
<h:outputText value="Description">   
 </f:facet> 
e var="data" value="mBean.dataList"><h:outputText value="#{data.description}"/>   
</h:panalGrid>   
</h:column>
```